# How can I install a legacy PIP version with python 2.6.6 or python 2.7.5?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, python-2.x

I'm struggling to install the python **pip** module on my centOS server which is running on python2.6.6(centOS 6) or python 2.7.5(CentOS7). Due to some reasons I'm not able to upgrade the python version to 3 or later. So in the case, how can I install a legacy PIP version line pip 20 with my python2.6 or python 2.7 platform?
Thanks.

Comment: Python 2 is to be no longer supported soon: https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/

Comment: @loa_in_ How soon?

Comment: As of January 1st, 2020 no new bug reports, fixes, or changes will be made to Python 2, and Python 2 is no longer supported.

Comment: That's extremely soon. Over a year ago.

Comment: @loa_in_ So your "soon" is in the past?

Comment: as per PIP website,--' PIP20.3 is the last version supported python 2..', that's why I'm asking-- I just want to install the pip v.20 or earlier version on my python 2 platform, any idea?

Comment: https://bootstrap.pypa.io/2.6/, https://bootstrap.pypa.io/2.7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get-pip.py` for 2.7. Here's an example in a `centos:7` Docker container:

```sh
$ python -V
Python 2.7.5
$ curl -fsSL -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py
$ python get-pip.py --no-python-version-warning && rm -f get-pip.py
$ python -m pip --version
pip 20.3.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

Docs: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py. (Though admittedly, they don't go out of their way to point out the presence of the 2.6/2.7 branches, given that Python 2 is prominently EOL.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Brad. Just follow the steps as you said I have got the pip 20.3.4 installed and I'm finally able to get the service up and running again:).Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Python 2, you most likely have pip. Try `python2 -m pip install foobar`.

Turns out that in CentOS7 `pip` is not available in distro repos by default. You need to `yum install epel-release` to enable the EPEL repo, which in turn contains `pip`: `yum install python-pip`.

So do this: (as root/using `sudo`)

```
yum install epel-release
yum makecache
yum install python-pip
```

Comment: Thanks loa_in. But when I type in 'python2 -m pip install foobar', I got an Error '/usr/bin/python2: No module named pip'

Comment: As per PIP website---'pip is already installed if you are using Python 2 >=2.7.9 or Python 3 >=3.4 downloaded from python.org ...'   Actually I'm using python 2.7.5 which comes with the centOS 7 system.

Comment: @Dacman2018 Here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/ you can read: `If you installed Python from a package manager on Linux, you should always install pip for that Python installation using the same source.`

Comment: "If you have Python 2, you most likely have pip." - not really. As you point out yourself, it is common for stuff like CentOS to just have easy_install and (maybe) setuptools out of the box.