# pip: sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}") with Python 3.5

Tags: python, pip

i am having a trouble with pip and pip3.
I am trying to install requirements and it shows an error. When i write pip3 or pip --version it show this error.

```
jumphost@jumphost-VirtualBox:~$ pip3 --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import __main__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py", line
21, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main
  File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If i am trying to install, it showed this

```
jumphost@jumphost-VirtualBox:~/kubespray$ pip install -r requirements.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import __main__
  File
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-21.0-py2.7.egg/pip/__main__.py",
line 21, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main
  File
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-21.0-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/cli/main.py",
line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
jumphost@jumphost-VirtualBox:~/kubespray$ pip3 install -r requirements.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import __main__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/__main__.py", line
21, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main
  File
"/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I didn't found a right answer so this is the reason why i ask you. Thanks !
I tried remove python, pip, python3 and pip3 multipletimes but still same problem.

Comment: f-strings were introduced in Python 3.6. I'm not sure how, but somehow you managed to break your installation by installing a Python 3.6 pip on your Python 3.5 interpreter

Comment: And how can I repare this ?

Comment: reinstall Python

Comment: More correctly: upgrade Python3, and pip dropped Python2 support, AFAIK

Comment: i removed all pythons via sudo apt-get remove --purge python*** and install python3 and pzthon3-pip and still same error

Comment: @DeepSpace i'm not sure if this is OP's fault here; I suspect some distros are incorrectly pulling versions of pip that dont' support the given python.

Comment: You cannot purge Python completely because it's an OS requirement. And depending on your ubuntu version, Python 3.6+ is not immediately available via apt; you need to add a PPA (or install miniconda3)

Comment: Solved, thank you guys.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

pip has dropped support for Python 2 and 3.5.  You will need to use a version-specific branch, assuming that your Python version is 3.5:

```sh
curl -fsSL https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.5/get-pip.py | python3.5
```

`get-pip.py` reference: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py

Related: [How can I install a legacy PIP version with python 2.6.6 or python 2.7.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65900292/7954504)

Better yet, as suggested in the comments, install a newer version of Python that is [not end-of-life](https://devguide.python.org/devcycle/#end-of-life-branches).

Comment: lifesaver great

Comment: I may be late in the reply but I'm using a server right now in which I cannot update python, so I have to use python 3.5. I get the same error as the person who asked the original question 
```sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")                                  
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```

and using the curl command does not solve the issue, the terminal says it installed pip 20.3.4, but unfortunately the syntax error still shows up. Do you happen to know what to do?