# ubuntu16.04 pip3 broken after upgrading

Tags: pip, ubuntu-16.04, python-3.5

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 to work. There is a need from my work to upgrade pip.

I was using the command:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

After that, every time I call the command pip3 will get the same error:

```
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 11, in main
    from pip._internal.utils.entrypoints import _wrapper
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/entrypoints.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 57
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                               ^
```

I've tried to search solution by myself and followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66212924/pip-sys-stderr-writeferror-exc-with-python-3-5) to try to deal with the issue.

This is the command I tried:

```
curl -fsSL -o- https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/3.5/get-pip.py | python3
```

However, after I tried the command, I got another issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 23974, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 199, in main
  File "<stdin>", line 121, in bootstrap
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from setuptools.dist import Distribution
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 585
    license_files: Optional[List[str]] = self.metadata.license_files
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there any other way to fix this issue except remove and install python3.5 again? because the python3.5 is used in the Ubuntu 16.04 OS, if I remove it the system will break.

Thank you very much.